# How to change dependent jar at runtime in a Spring application without restarting the application itself?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, runtime

### Context

Let's say we have a Spring app (`spring.jar`) dependent on `lib.jar`. This jar would have a method
String getData(). This method would return the letter "A".

We would run the spring app with the following command:

```
java -cp "spring.jar:lib.jar" Main
```

After the spring application starts successfully, we can test it and surely we see that Spring shows the letter 'A' from the `lib.jar`.

### The Question

Is there anyway to override the `lib.jar` (that will return now the letter 'B') and have this reflected in the spring server without restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml file add the spring dev tools dependency. This allows you run the application after any changes without restarting the application

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @S Badal, Thank you for your answer, but that solution builds spring automatically when a change within has been made. The problem is that `lib.jar` from my question is not part of the spring framework, so changing `lib.jar` will not trigger a rebuild in spring. And I would like to see the chages without having to restart or rebuild spring.